# How to center tables within page for two parallel div?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 parallel div and within each div there are one or more stacked tables.

I'm trying to center the tables in the page, so for the table in left `<div>` should be moved to the right and table in right `<div>` should be moved to the left. I'd like a fixed horizontal separation between tables of 50px.

With my current CSS code I´m able to move the table in right `<div>` to the left, but I'm stuck in how to move the table in left `<div>` to the right. Thanks for any help.

**Current output**
[image]

**Output I'm looking for**
[image]

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Table Generator</title>
    <style>
      body {
        text-align: center;
      }

      #inputContainer {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }

      #tableContainer {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        margin: 0 -25px;
        padding: 40px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      .tableWrapperLeft {
        width: 50%;
        margin: 0 25px;
        border: 2px solid yellow;
      }

      .tableWrapperRight {
        width: 50%;
        margin: 0 25px;
        border: 2px solid yellow;
      }

      table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        width: 288px;
        height: 288px;
      }

      td {
        border: 1px dotted black;
        text-align: center;
      }

      td:first-child {
        border-left: 1px dotted black;
      }

      tr:first-child td {
        border-top: 1px dotted black;
      }

      .tableWrapperRight table {
        border: 2px solid green;
      }

      .tableWrapperLeft table {
        border: 2px solid green;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="tableContainer">
      <div class="tableWrapperLeft">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>V</td><td>W</td><td>E</td><td>G </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>G</td><td>K</td><td>L</td><td>D </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>W</td><td>F</td><td>U</td><td>N </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>G</td><td>A</td><td>Q</td><td>L </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="tableWrapperRight">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>U</td><td>N</td><td>P</td><td>H </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Q</td><td>L</td><td>R</td><td>B </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>J</td><td>B</td><td>I</td><td>N </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>D</td><td>A</td><td>H</td><td>T </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

With solution provided by @fatm, I have issues in left "div", if each "div" has more than one table and looks like this.

[image]

Comment: add display: flex and justify-content: flex-end to tableWrapperLeft div.

Comment: @MohamedMagdy Thank you, but doesn´t seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change the `flex-direction` of a certain `div` then just use flex start or end for alignment to able to achieve.

```css
body {
        text-align: center;
      }

      #inputContainer {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }

      #tableContainer {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        margin: 0 -25px;
        padding: 40px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      .tableWrapperLeft {
        width: 50%;
        margin: 0 25px;
        border: 2px solid yellow;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: flex-end;
      }

      .tableWrapperRight {
        width: 50%;
        margin: 0 25px;
        border: 2px solid yellow;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: flex-start;
      }

      table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        width: 288px;
        height: 288px;
      }

      td {
        border: 1px dotted black;
        text-align: center;
      }

      td:first-child {
        border-left: 1px dotted black;
      }

      tr:first-child td {
        border-top: 1px dotted black;
      }

      .tableWrapperRight table {
        border: 2px solid green;
      }

      .tableWrapperLeft table {
        border: 2px solid green;
      }
```

```html
 <body>
    <div id="tableContainer">
      <div class="tableWrapperLeft">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>V</td><td>W</td><td>E</td><td>G </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>G</td><td>K</td><td>L</td><td>D </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>W</td><td>F</td><td>U</td><td>N </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>G</td><td>A</td><td>Q</td><td>L </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="tableWrapperRight">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>U</td><td>N</td><td>P</td><td>H </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Q</td><td>L</td><td>R</td><td>B </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>J</td><td>B</td><td>I</td><td>N </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>D</td><td>A</td><td>H</td><td>T </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

#inputContainer {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#tableContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 -25px;
  padding: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tableWrapperLeft {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 25px;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
}


}
.tableWrapperRight {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 25px;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  width: 288px;
  height: 288px;
}
td {
  border: 1px dotted black;
  text-align: center;
}
td:first-child {
  border-left: 1px dotted black;
}
tr:first-child td {
  border-top: 1px dotted black;
}
.tableWrapperRight table {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
.tableWrapperLeft table {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="tableContainer">
  <div class="tableWrapperLeft">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>V</td>
        <td>W</td>
        <td>E</td>
        <td>G </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>G</td>
        <td>K</td>
        <td>L</td>
        <td>D </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>W</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>U</td>
        <td>N </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>G</td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>Q</td>
        <td>L </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="tableWrapperRight">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>U</td>
        <td>N</td>
        <td>P</td>
        <td>H </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Q</td>
        <td>L</td>
        <td>R</td>
        <td>B </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>J</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>I</td>
        <td>N </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>D</td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>H</td>
        <td>T </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but I have an issue. If each div element has 2 or more tables, in left div appear joined horizontal, not in stacked mode

Comment: Please check my update in original post.